# Rack::Builder and Rack::TryStatic doesn't work

Tags: ruby, rack, middleman

I have a [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com) app which I am serving using `Rack::TryStatic`.

Here is the `config.ru`.

```
use Rack::TryStatic,
  root: 'build',
  urls: %w[/],
  try: ['.html', 'index.html', '/index.html']

run lambda{ |env|
  four_oh_four_page = File.expand_path("../build/404.html", __FILE__)
  [ 404, { 'Content-Type'  => 'text/html'}, [ File.read(four_oh_four_page) ]]
}
```

My understanding is that when you use a `config.ru` with `run`, `map` or `use`
methods, they are converted to a `Rack::Builder` object.

I've tried wrapping this config in a `Rack::Builder` object like this:

```
app = Rack::Builder.new do

  use Rack::TryStatic,
    root: 'build',
    urls: %w[/],
    try: ['.html', 'index.html', '/index.html']

  run lambda{ |env|
    four_oh_four_page = File.expand_path("../build/404.html", __FILE__)
    [ 404, { 'Content-Type'  => 'text/html'}, [ File.read(four_oh_four_page) ]]
  }
end

run app
```

When I do this, I get the 404 page for all requests.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in the current released version of `TryStatic` that [has been fixed in master](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/commit/1c13e9ed73d8e0a3d685e78972a1283f149e4d5a), where the `try` array is being lost when used in way that causes the middleware to be reinitialized.

You can avoid this by making sure the app only get s initialized once by using `to_app`:

```
run app.to_app
```

or equivalently use `app` instead of `new`:

```
app = Rack::Builder.app do
  # ...
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I used `Rack::Builder.app` and it works now :)